# Как сделать геттер и сеттер для класса-наследника?

Tags: python, классы, getter, setter

Как сделать геттер и сеттер в классе Name чтобы я мог менять __value класса Name?
Например когда пытаюсь дать значение:

```
n = Name()
n.value = 'Ivan'
print(n.value)
```

получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_Name__value'
```

Реализация классов:

```
class Field:
def __init__(self):
    self.__value = None

@property
def value(self):
    return self.__value

@value.setter
def value(self, value):
    self.__value = value


class Name(Field):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

@property
def value(self):
    return super().value

@value.setter
def value(self, name):
    super().value = name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сделать вот так

```
class Name(Field):

    def __init__(self, value=""):
        super().value = value

    @property
    def fvalue(self):
        return super().value

    @value.setter
    def fvalue(self, name):
        super().value = name
        
        
n = Name()
n.value = "Ivan"
print(n.value)
```

Comment: Но я хочу использовать из родительского класса. Почему не работает при помощи super()?

Comment: Извини не заметил наследование, спать пора))) Переименуй функции гетеров и сетеров, я буквально для проверки поставил fvalue (но не советую так делать) и все заработало. Вся проблема в том что питон не понимает ему брать функцию или переменную вот и выдавал ошибку. по крайней мере я себе так это объясняю

Answer (score 0):

Ну так у родительского класса и нет `value`, а есть `__value`. Нужно привести имена в соответствие и все будет работать.